# write data from MySQL database

Tags: php

I have been programming with asp for years now but I am very new to php.

I want to pull the data from the mysql database I created.

If I was to do the same job with asp;

```
<%
    Set ObjConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ObjConn.Open ("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serveraddress;DATABASE=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password")

SQL = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY PRODUCTNAME DESC" 
    Set objProducts = objConn.Execute(SQL)

    Do While not objProducts.EOF 
%>
<%=objProducts("PRODUCTNAME")%>
<%
    objProducts.MoveNext 
    Loop
%>
```

How do I do same thing with php?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("serveraddress", "username", "password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("databasename");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT PRODUCTNAME
                           FROM PRODUCTS 
                       ORDER BY PRODUCTNAME DESC");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["PRODUCTNAME"];
  }

  mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

### Recommendation

Never select columns that you will not use or display.

### Reference:

- [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
- [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)